# Colocar mismo tamaño de BOX CSS?

Tags: css

Tengo un label con un checkbox y una Lista:

```
    <label style="margin-left:15px;">Solo Activos:&nbsp;@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isActiveTest)@*</label>*@@*<br />*@
@*<label style="margin-left:15px; width:100%;">*@Categoria:&nbsp;@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Categories, (SelectBaseListAdapter<int, string>)ViewBag.ListDisplayCategory)</label>@*<br />*@
```

Me gustaría que ambos figuararan con el mismo tamaño de Box (caja).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿a cuál caja te refieres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por la respuesta, de este modo pude lograrlo: `

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    zoom: 1.2;
    margin-bottom:-3px;
}
```

Y...

```
<label style="margin-left:15px;">Solo Activos:&nbsp;@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isActiveTest)</label> <label style="margin-bottom:10px;">Categoria:&nbsp;@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Categories,(SelectBaseListAdapter<int, string>)ViewBag.ListDisplayCategory)</label><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Usted necesita mejorar la estructura del form. Puede usar el `flex-box`
remove tags break-line y los estilos en linea.

```
<div class="filter-label">
  <label>Solo Activos:&nbsp;@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isActiveTest)@*</label>
  <label>*@Categoria:&nbsp;@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Categories, (SelectBaseListAdapter<int, string>)ViewBag.ListDisplayCategory)</label>
<div>

.filter-label {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 width: 100%;
}
.filter-label label {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Espero que haya ayudado.